# How to get the specific file(txt) with volatility?

Tags: volatility

I tried to filescan,and I see the .txt I want to open.But how can I open the txt?

I am new with volatility,and I tried more than 6 hours to get the txt.I tried dumpfiles,but I finally get lots of files that does'nt match the file I want to get.

Comment: please,is there anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

get the imagebaseadress of the file and run db(imagebaseadress) inside volshell you should see the contents